# 'Record Espresso Test' box isn't displayed in my project on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I wanted to use Espresso to create UI tests for my application but when I clicked on 'Record Espresso Test', the box used to list the current action isn't displayed. However, it's working on other projects. I speak about that one :

espresso record box

[image: 1]

No error message is returned. I implemented all espresso dependencies and I m working on 'Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2'. I try to launch it on the Android Studio of a friend and it's also not working. Did someone encounter the same trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:
I wasn't able to figure out a way to solve the issue but with the new Android Studio release (Flamingo) the issue is fixed.

**Earlier Answer**:
Currently, I am also facing the same issue and I am unable to find any solution for the same. But one solution that I can suggest temporarily is to downgrade your android studio version to `Dolphin` and it should work without any issues.

Note that, certain AGP versions do not work with `Android Studio Dolphin` and hence that might case build issues. This is the very reason I am unable to even downgrade. In case, I find some other solution which I have to defintely, I'll post it here.